# Склонение названий профессиональных праздников

Tags: грамматика

Подскажите, как правильно написать: *Награждается в связи с профессиональным праздником "День кооперации"?*

Answer (score 4):

Награждается в связи с профессиональным праздником – Международным днем кооперации (Днем кооперации).

Кавычки в таких случаях практически не используются, поэтому приложение и имя собственное согласуются в падеже, название обособляется с помощью тире.

Пример: Поздравляем Вас с праздником - Днем защитника Отечества!

Answer (score 1):

Официальные названия всякого рода праздников, содержащих слово "день", не содержат кавычек (об исключениях я не знаю), поэтому их использование в подобных сочетаниях просто невозможно. По той же причине они склоняются по обычным правилам, первое слово пишется с заглавной, остальные со со строчной, если нет иных причин для заглавной. Откуда там появилось слово "международный", я не знаю, с остальным согласен.